# can't delete resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

`az group delete -n blah -y`

yields:

> Operation returned an invalid status 'Conflict'

there's an old Send Grid resource in the group.  I've tried deleting that via the portal & I get:

> Deletion of your SendGrid Account failed.

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid has some technical problems. You should check first with SendGrid official support website if this is the issue. When you are registering SendGrid account via Azure you are getting standard SendGrid plan. May be that might be something that has some issue with it or may be first Send grid account connected has to be deleted and its related resources disabled and then only sendgrid resource can be deleted from Azure. Please find the below link for more details: -

https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/cancel-your-account

Comment: Thanks for the idea  but I don't really care if I leave a dangling resource in SendGrid.  I should be able delete it from Azure no matter what.  Too time consuming 